# WinApi: Get Control Name of COM Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, com, ui-automation

I want to replace my current UI automation tool (QTP) with .Net framework. 
I need to test VB6 (COM) application.

One of the fundamentals of framework is using the form name.
So far I failed to find a way to get this data using Win API.

There is only one constrain for the solution and its that the solution MUST rely on .Net code - meaning: **no commercials tools allowed**.

Does anyone is familiar with this subject?

These links are my major references:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405(d=printer).aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianmcm/archive/2006/01/17/getting-the-winforms-id-of-a-control.aspx
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianmcm/archive/2006/01/23/516418.aspx
4. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/558930-really-need-help-sendmessage-wm_getcontrolname

All of them suggest to use SendMessage in order to retrieve the form's data, which I failed to do.

I will be happy to for any idea for this issue.

Thank you very much.

The C# code

```
 public static class VbAdapter : IAdapter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets form internal name (design-time name).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Form handle</param>
    /// <returns>string. Form's internal name.</returns>
    public static string GetFormInternalName(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        int _ctrlNameMsg = 0;
        //_ctrlNameMsg = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GETCONTROLNAME"); //For .Net forms
        _ctrlNameMsg = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage("Get_CONTROLNAME"); //for vb6 forms

        return GetControlName(hWnd, _ctrlNameMsg);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get control internal name using its handle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Control handle</param>
    /// <param name="msg">Control Name Message</param>
    /// <returns>string.</returns>
    private static string GetControlName(IntPtr hWnd, int msg)
    {
        //vars

        uint size = 65536; //size of memory to be allocated
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[size]; //win form internal name buffer

        IntPtr bufferMem = IntPtr.Zero; //pointer to memory buffer contain the internal name
        IntPtr written = IntPtr.Zero;          //number of bytes written so far
        IntPtr retHandle = IntPtr.Zero;         //returned handle
        IntPtr hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;       //Process handle
        IntPtr fileHandle = IntPtr.Zero;          //File handle

        bool retVal = false;

        //in case non Win32Nt OS version - throw exception
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT)
            throw new Win32Exception("Oprating System is not supportted for this module.\nThis module is supportted on Win32Nt OS only.");
        try
        {
            uint procId = GetProcessIdFromHWnd(hWnd);
            //get process deatails
            hProcess = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(
                WindowsConsts.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
                WindowsConsts.PROCESS_VM_READ |
                WindowsConsts.PROCESS_VM_WRITE,
                false,
                procId);

            //Todo: Export to OpenProcess Method in native class
            if (hProcess.ToInt64() == 0) throw new Win32Exception();

            bufferMem = NativeMethods.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                new UIntPtr(size),
                WindowsConsts.MEM_RESERVE | WindowsConsts.MEM_COMMIT,
                NativeMethods.PageProtection.ReadWrite);

            //Todo: Export to OpenProcess Method in native class
            if (hProcess.ToInt64() == 0) throw new Win32Exception();

            //Send message to the control requesting it's name
            retHandle = NativeMethods.SendMessage(hWnd, msg, new IntPtr(size), bufferMem);

            //Get TVITEM from shared memory
            if (!NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, bufferMem, byteArray, new UIntPtr(size), written))
                throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return ByteArrayToString(byteArray);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts byte array to string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="byteArray">The byte array.</param>
    /// <returns>string.</returns>
    private static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteArray).TrimEnd('\0');
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the process id using its handle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">The handle</param>
    /// <returns>uint. The process Id.</returns>
    private static uint GetProcessIdFromHWnd(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        uint pId;
        NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pId);

        return pId;
    }
}
 internal class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle,
        uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress,
        UIntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, PageProtection flProtect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress,
        UIntPtr dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr MapViewOfFile(IntPtr hFileMappingObject, uint
        dwDesiredAccess, uint dwFileOffsetHigh, uint dwFileOffsetLow,
        UIntPtr dwNumberOfBytesToMap);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool UnmapViewOfFile(IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(IntPtr hFile,
        IntPtr lpFileMappingAttributes, PageProtection flProtect, int dwMaximumSizeHigh,
        int dwMaximumSizeLow, string lpName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, UIntPtr nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern void MoveMemoryFromByte(IntPtr dest, ref byte src, int size);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    internal static extern void MoveMemoryToByte(ref byte dest, IntPtr src, int size);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

    [Flags]
    internal enum PageProtection : uint
    {
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        Readonly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        Guard = 0x100,
        NoCache = 0x200,
        WriteCombine = 0x400,
    }
}
```

Comment: All the references above are for WinForms; VB6 is a whole different technology that predates that. Do you have any access to the source of these apps? I think it's possible to write a ActiveX control that you can add to a form that can explore the other controls on the form and then perhaps extract some information from them that way, but I don't know if there's any way to get information about a VB form from outside the process.

Comment: @BrendanMcK: Thank you for you reply. I currently work on QTP. One of its tools is Gui spy which extract all required objects properties. It does it from another process (I think by SendMessage Win API function). So it's possible, but might be very hard to do.

Comment: What do you mean by the "form name"? Do you mean the class name, i.e. the type?

Comment: @RobertT: Hi Robert. I don't mean the class name. I need the actual form name (meaning the instance name). Are you familiar with the subject?

Comment: I can't tell from your question whether you have control over the VB forms you are looking for. Do you have the source? Can you change and compile them? The reason I'm asking is that RegisterWindowMessage allows you to create a NEW message, one that did not exist before. For this to work, the VB app must also register the same message. It must then listen for that unique message number and respond with the required information, in this case the form name. If this does not sound like the kind of thing you have in your environment, RegisterWindowMessage is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @RobertT: Hi again. I understand your suggestion, but Any type (or level) of API usage cannot be implemented in the tested application. As I commented earlier QTP have the ability to recognize VB and ActiveX UI object. since there are too many constrains using it, I want to do the same using my own C# code.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is NO to being able to edit the tested applications. And I'm also assuming that the tested applications do not already register a "Get_CONTROLNAME" message. This means that you cannot use RegisterWindowMessage and SendMessage. You can only use that if both the testing application and the tested application implement it. Therefore QTP is using something else. So, we don't know what the answer yet, but we know it's possible, and we know it's not SendMessage. I will continue with the investigation...

Comment: Everything I've said so far is based on the assumption that we're talking about compiled programs, i.e. the tested program is an EXE. Am I correct or are you talking about uncompiled applications, i.e. projects and source files that are being tested using QTP?

Comment: @RobertT: Thank you for your reply. 1. The tested application cannot be modified 2. It is exe file.

Comment: @RobertT: As I start to figure it out, it seem to me that the solution relies on 3 WinApi dlls: ole32.dll, oleaut32.dll and oleacc.dll. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the right direction. I suspect you will find the answer in the very poorly documented oleacc.dll. I remember being very frustrated by the lack of information, especially on oleacc. Unfortunately I haven't worked with that stuff for more than 10 years, and even then I hardly knew the beginnings of it, so I don't think I will be of much help. But I'll keep thinking about it. Good luck!