# Alternative methods to access controls that aren't exposed by MSAA/UIAutomation

Tags: c#, winapi, coded-ui-tests

I am writing CodedUI tests for an App that was written in VB6 and need to do an assertion on a number of different labels. Labels in VB6 do not implement MSAAA and so they do not appear in Spy++ or Inspector. Changing the application code for automated testing will be an uphill battle.

The tests were originally written in Rational and Rational's object inspector is able to get the label and most of it's properties. So I know that it is possible to get the information that I am looking for. I assume that Rational uses something in the winapi to get access to the label's properties, I assume something has to draw the label on the screen.

Any one else run into this problem? I am open to any idea that doesn't involve changing the source code of the application I am testing.

Comment: I had the same issue, started writting an extension for CUIT that would connect to the VB6 app using COM and WCF. I couldn't find any alternative at the time. We stopped work on it though as it was a big job and we could see the lifespan of the app coming to an end. It would be interesting to see how rational does it. do you need to add any plugins to the VB6 app?

Comment: I wasn't here when Rational was implemented, but I have been told there weren't any extra modules added to the VB6 app to get it to work with Rational. I would be interested to know how you were approaching getting the values out of VB6 labels.

Comment: Basically had to write VB6 code to get the value of each property/control type. Then it would send it back to the Coded UI extension via COM for the VB6 to .net boundary and then WCF to send it back to the extension. in theory it should work but its a big job. I started documenting it here http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/creating-a-coded-ui-test-extension/

Comment: It could use Messaging, I found this link that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151892/winapi-get-control-name-of-com-forms
We started looking into messaging but it requires a WindowHandle to send the information back. The CUIT extension though has no UI and is dynamically loaded at runtime.

Comment: I thought at the time you would need a VB6 plugin that sends messages to the CodedUI Test plugin, that would require the Coded UI Test to have a window handle. Looking at that link though i think it might be possible to have the CodedUI plugin get the information directly without he VB6 plugin. If your interested i might be able to help out with the Coded UI extension. Perhaps an open source project needs to be started?

Comment: When I posted this initially I didn't realize that CodedUI tests were not getting the actual name/accessible name from the VB6 application. I just assumed that the problems I had in searching for controls was from the cesspool that is the code base for this particular application.

Comment: Legacy VB6 apps are probably going to be around for the foreseeable future. I know I would probably get a fair bit of value out of writing an opensource extension to get accurate values from VB6 applications. I think a fair number of other people would as well.

Comment: I've had a bit of time to look at this. I was able to get basic information through messages but its still limited. Name property of controls is not exposed so there is no unique way to identify them. I found you could us the id but this seems to change when the control layout changes. VB6 Labels do not seem to be exposed at all. I'd love to know how rational does it

Comment: Yeah on the VB6 labels I gave up trying to get the values from the application and am just using an OCR on an image of the label which is a pain but it works well enough.