# Does Coded UI tool support desktop applications developed in VB6?

Tags: vb6, coded-ui-tests

We have a desktop application in our company that was developed in **VB 6** 15 years ago. There is no automation in place and the management decided to have regression tests automated to save the vast amount of time spent for Regression Tests.

We are analysing different third party Automation tools that suit for our application. We did a proof of concept with **TestComplete** and not everybody is very happy with the tool as it doesn't support many VB 6 controls like true db grid, etc;

There is not much support available since its community is not as big as the famous automation test frameworks like **Selenium**. Personally, I feel that **TestComplete** has become ancient and not many people are using it.

Can anybody explain me if Coded UI support **VB 6** applications? If yes, what are the pros and cons of this tool?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538283/alternative-methods-to-access-controls-that-arent-exposed-by-msaa-uiautomation) and the comments beneath it, where people are discussing Coded UI tests with VB6

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce9c1c11-71e1-419b-8621-f7712e61cff2/coded-ui-test-for-a-vb6-application?forum=vstest  and   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @AdrianHHH I checked first before I raised a question in stackoverflow. But, couldn't find VB6 in the list.

Comment: Does it absence not tell you something? The page is titled *"Supported Configurations and Platforms for Coded UI Tests and Action Recordings"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i would recommend you to do is that investigate the Type of each controls in your application. If these are WinControls, then it's a positive sign, you can automate it by CodedUI.

Technically, CodedUI can automate the applications having the controls either WinControls or HtmlControls, irrespective of how and what it was build by.

So try spying the controls in your application using 'Cross hair Tool' provided in codedUI and find out the control type.(If you don't have VSTS in your machine, try 30 day trial and investigate).

Pros:
When it comes to Pros, this tool just does what the other tools do. But Still It gives you wide range of automation facilities, you can do API tests, Performance, Load tests as well. And you can link your automation methods with the manual testcases in TFS and MTM which makes the tracking very easy. Ex: you can easily track if a particular manual testcase is automated or not.
Cons:
 you don't find solutions online when you search for it. you're almost aon your own. if you are good in oops, this tool is a gem. and this is a licenced tool.

Hope it helps. Good Luck !!